# Changing the default copy constructor C++

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

I am having problems understanding how to override the default copy constructor in C++. I am receiving no compilation errors. The previous examples show to me our of the pattern below. Below are listed excerpts from the files `HashTable.cpp` and `Hashtable.h`.

**Hashtable.h**

```
HashTable& operator=(const HashTable& other);`
```

**HashTable.cpp**

```
const HashTable& HashTable::operator=(const HashTable& other) {
    std::cout << "EQUAL OPERATOR METHOD" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
HashTable ht1 {9};
HashTable ht2 { ht1 };
```

Although when I compile, it appears as if the copy constructor is not called. To clarify, I am trying to copy one variable to the other.

It is worth noting that I am coding in c++11 on Ubuntu 14.04. As coding c++ in Ubuntu has already had many hangups for me, I am uncertain if this is c++ or ubuntu problem. I have spent quite some time trying to figure out what is going on here so please do not down vote.

Comment: `HashTable::operator=(const HashTable& other)` is the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: That is the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: You need to override the constructor `HashTable::Hashtable(const HashTable& other)`, not the assignment operator.

Comment: @T.C. my apologies, been a long day. Updated.

Comment: OK, looks like you are more confused than I thought. `HashTable ht2 { ht1 };` uses the copy constructor, not the copy assignment operator.

Comment: In your main function do `HashTable ht2 = ht1;` to invoke the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @PaulRooney That's still the copy constructor. `HashTable ht2; ht2 = ht1;` would use the copy assignment operator.

Comment: ah ok thanks for setting me straight on that one.

Comment: Can you please decide whether you're asking about *copy constructor* or *copy-assignment operator* and update the title accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you wrote above is the overriding of [`copy assignment operator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), but, according to your `main.cpp`, seems like you need the [`copy constructor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) (don't be scared by the amount of text in these descriptions, it's really easy to understand). Try the following code:

**HashTable.h**

```
class HashTable
{
private:
    // private members declaration...
public:
    // public members declaration...
    HashTable(const HashTable& other);
}
```

**HashTable.cpp**

```
// Copy constructor implementation
HashTable::Hashtable(const HashTable& other){
    // implement your own copy constructor
    std::cout << "OVERRIDED COPY CONSTRUCTOR METHOD" << std::endl;
    // This is the constructor, so don't have to return anything
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
HashTable ht2(ht1);
```

**PS:** Not sure about `HashTable ht2 {ht1}` (using the symbols `{` and `}`). Seems like it's `C++14` feature, according to the comment of **M.M**.

Comment: `HashTable ht2 { ht1 };` is a C++11 feature and it is the same has `HashTable ht2 ( ht1 );` in C++14.  My comment points out that, prior to the application of a defect report, those two codes might have been different in C++11, but only if the class were equipped with particular constructors that superseded the copy-constructor

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the sample code in your question is a copy assignment. The difference between the copy constructor and the copy assignment is that, the copy construction can only be called when initializing an object. After an object is initialized and you want to pass another initialized object to it, the copy assignment is rather called. 
So in the main function since `ht1`was passed to `ht2` while initializing it, it will rather call the copy constructor. But in your code, you defined the copy assignment and not the copy constructor. 
check out [copy assignment c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/) for more details about the difference between the copy assignment and the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**HashTable::operator=(const HashTable& other)** is assignment opperator. Copy constructor should be written as HashTable::HashTable(const HashTable& other).

"**HashTable ht2 { ht1 }**" is not invoking copy-constructor, it's actually invoking initializer_list: "**HashTable(initializer_list< HashTable>)**"

To invoke copy constructor you should write
**HashTable hash(anotherHashTable)** in your main.cpp.

Comment: In C++14, `HashTable ht2 { ht1 };` invokes the copy-constructor regardless of what other details the class has.  Under a proposal for C++17  (and in the publication of C++11 before it was changed via a defect report), this would invoke `HashTable(initializer_list< HashTable>)`, *but only if such a constructor had actually been declared*.  In the absence of such a constructor, the next cabs off the rank are a forwarding constructor that forwards all args (if present); and then the copy-constructor.